How does it follow from the maximum modulus principle that an entire function is constant if its real part is bounded above?
I've read this on math stack exchange:
An entire function whose real part is bounded above must be constant.
Apparently the questioner wants to know how you can use the maximum modulus principle to prove that an entire function is constant if its real part is bounded above. I would like to know the same, but unfortunately in all the comments and answers Liouville's theorem is used instead. May anyone suggest now how the former result can be used?

$g(z)=e^{f(z)}$ is a bounded entire function and let $M=\sup |g(z)|$; then if $M$ is a maximum so attained at a finite point, the maximum modulus theorem tells us $g$ (hence $f$) constant; otherwise $h(z)=g(1/z)$ is a bounded holomorphic function on the punctured plane, hence it can be extended to an entire function and it attains the maximum modulus $M$ at $0$ by the above so is constant again by maximum modulus

Great argument, Conrad! Would it be possible to argue like this to derive Liouville's theorem from the maximum modulus principle?

Is the provided argument in fact a derivation of Liouville's theorem from the maximum modulus principle?

Yes of course - maximum modulus is at the root of liouville too; this  being said maximum modulus is a consequence of the power series representation as is the usual proof of liouville

Ok. Would it be possible to argue the other way around and derive the maximum modulus principle from Liouville's theorem?

Maximum modulus is a local property while liouville is global and usually one can work local to global but not vice versa; liouville implies that one cannot have global maximum for an entire function but says nothing about the impossibility of having local maxima
